# connecting to database in c# via IP\DEV

Tags: c#, sql, database-connection, connection-string

Im Trying to connect to a database on a SQL server Located on 192.168.100.42\DEV but i keep getting a network related error see below by code and then the error , If any one can help it would be appreciated

```
 private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      string connectionString = "Data Source=192.168.100.42\Dev;Initial Catalog=UNIS;User ID=sa;Password=Password1!";
      using (SqlCommand scmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.searchName"))
      {
            scmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            scmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@name", cbUserName.Text));

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(scmd);
            SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);

            conn.Open();
            scmd.Connection = conn;

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
            dataGridView2.ReadOnly = true;
            dataGridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

            conn.Close();

        }
```

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Comment: Did configure the sql server to allow remote connections?

Comment: Hi found the problem thanx I forgot the \\ 192.168.100.42\\Dev as always its the little things @Soner